# Hold frame UIView from Parent View

Tags: ios

I have UITableViewCell

[image]

I use edit mode `self.tableMail.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;`
when tableview edit mode

[image]

i want `lbTime 22/08/2013` hold position on cell before edit mode, don't translate with cell?

Comment: Make sure your subviews are added to the cell's `contentView` and not the cell itself.

Comment: Okie, i resloved: [self addSubview:lbTime] instead [seld.contentView addSubview:lbTime]

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that all of your cell contents are added to the `contentView` and that you have configured them with auto-resizing / auto-layout rules such that the label will keep a static distance to the right edge.

If the text in the cell could be bigger then you might want to add logic to your custom cell class to layout the subviews specifically when it enters and exits editing mode.